# How would one differentiate the exponential map?

Tags: differential-geometry, riemannian-geometry, mathematical-physics, general-relativity

In General Relativity if $(M,g,\nabla)$ is spacetime being $\nabla$ the Levi-Civita connection, then we can define on a geodesically convex set $U\subset M$ the map $\sigma : U\times U\to \mathbb{R}$

$$\sigma(x,y)=\dfrac{1}{2}g_x(\exp_x^{-1}(y),\exp_x^{-1}(y))$$

in other words, $\sigma(x,y)$ is a half of the geodesic distance squared between two points $x,y\in U$.

Given a chart $(x,V)$ (here we are thinking that $U\subset V$), we can then consider the covariant derivative $\nabla_\mu$ with respect to $\frac{\partial}{\partial x^\mu}$. I want to compute objects like

$$\nabla_\mu \sigma(x,y)$$

$$\nabla_\mu \nabla_\nu \sigma(x,y)$$

with the understanding that the derivative keeps $x$ fixed. So $x$ is a parameter here.

The first derivative is obviously the partial, since $\nabla_X$ is $X$ itself on $C^\infty(M)$.

The issue is that we need to differentiate $\exp_x^{-1}$ and this doesn't seem trivial. All I know about $\exp_x$ is that it is a map $\exp_x : T_x M\to U$ which given $X\in T_xM$, if $\gamma_{x,X} : I\subset\mathbb{R}\to U$ is the unique geodesic with $\gamma_{x,X}(0)=x$ and $\gamma_{x,X}'(0)=X$ then $\exp_x(X)=\gamma_{x,X}(1)$.

I have no idea on how to differentiate this map, let alone its inverse.

So how do we compute $\nabla_\mu \sigma(x,y)$ with $x$ fixed? How the exponential map is differentiated?

Answer (score 1):

The differential of the exponential map is known for the Riemannian case (or at least we may have some information about it).

**Proposition** (*Gallot, Hulin, Lafontaine - Riemannian Geometry*, 3.46)
Let $m$ be a point of a Riemannian manifold $(M,g)$, and $u,v$ be two tangent vectors at $m$. Let $c$ be the geodesic $r \mapsto \exp_mrv$, and $Y$ be the Jacobi ﬁeld along $c$ such that $Y(0) = 0$ and $Y'(0) = u$. Then
$$
Y(r)=d_{tv}\exp_m\cdot ru.
$$

Looking at the proof of this proposition and the others needed to arrive at this point, I would say that there is no use of the positivity of the metric, but I could be wrong.